# Git GUI clients from which I can work on Unix work spaces from windows platform?

Tags: git

Is there any GIT GUI client which I can install on windows platform and can control my unix based workspace?

I have workspace on Unix machine and but as I have no permission to install Unix based UI on that machine. Is there any windows GIT gui client through which I can do ssh , sftp or any other connection and perform operation.

Answer (score 0):

I use git extentions which uses putty for ssh (comes with putty). Its free too.